# JDK license: modifying / copy of a JDK class allowed?

Tags: java, licensing

I am confused about the current (1.8) JDK license. Actually, I want to copy a class (from the javax namespace) and enhance it and use it in my project. Does the licence cover this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Oracle license at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html: Oracle grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable, limited license without fees to reproduce and distribute the Software, provided that (i) you distribute the Software complete and unmodified and only bundled as part of, and for the sole purpose of running, your Programs, (...)  (iii) you do not distribute additional software intended to replace any component(s) of the Software.

What your proposing is not to modify the original JDK, but get inspiration from the source code to write you own class? Since you're doing something extra that the original JDK didn't do, and you still bundle the original Oracle class, you should be OK. But I'm not a lawyer, and if you're worried, fire an email to Oracle directly.